# Data Model + Behaviour Architecture Design

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I can't post images yet but I am working on this model for a documenting tool.

I have objects(abstract) class and relationships class and properties class.

All of these hang from context class where I keep the environment vars and also has an object collection, a properties collection and a relationship collection.

Is it a good idea to make object inherit from context? so I can have all built in functionality and behaviour to be inherited to all object and relationships?

Or is it a better idea to separate this and create a base class (behaviour) which context, object, properties and relationships will inherit from all the functionality that I want to flow through the objects and also keep a collection of properties on this higher layer (behaviour) that can extend all objects and add properties as required to them?

I hope it is clear enough... it would be easier to post a diagram but I can't yet.

Here's a little pseudocode to show what I mean:

```
public abstract class Behaviour
{
    ToXML();
    JSonSerilize();
    Save();
    Display();
    Compare();
}


public abstract class Context : Behaviour
{
    public List<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
    public List<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
    AddObject();
}


public class Property : Context
{
    public Object ObjectRelated { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Object : Context
{
}

public abstract class Relationship : Context
{
        public Object Source { get; set; }

        public Object Target { get; set; }
}
```

OR

```
public abstract class Behaviour
{
    ToXML();
    JSonSerilize();
    Save();
    Display();
    Compare();
    public List<Property> Properties { get; set; }
}


public abstract class Context : Behaviour
{
    public List<Object> Objects { get; set; }
    public List<Relationship> Relationships { get; set; }
    AddProperty (Object, value) { base:Properties.Add}

}


public class Property : Behaviour
{
    public Object ObjectRelated { get; set; }
}

public abstract class Object : Behaviour
{
    AddProperty (Object, value) { base:Properties.Add}
}

public abstract class Relationship : Behaviour
{
     public Object Source { get; set; }

    public Object Target { get; set; }

    AddProperty (Object, value) { base:Properties.Add}
}
```

I quite like the second design where all objects (objects, relationships, context) can be extended in properties, but I don't like the fact that I would have to keep the properties collection on the upper class (Behaviour), seems too be too tightly coupled.
Any ideas, pros and cons?

FURTHER DETAILS: (Thanks NWard)

Goal: Core Library for documenting tool.
I want a generic core library that I could use to implement different scenarios of documentation. 
I want a separation on how these objects get persisted, serialized and manipulated to and from memory and the actual extension/implementation of it (2 Layers)

Requirements:
I need to be able to persist/transport via web service/odata/db/json the whole "Data Context class" with all its objects+properties and their relationships.

> Even if every class in your application needs to have a dynamically
>   generated list of Properties (why?)

Because I want to produce a core object type and also a relationship type and a Data Context Type capable to be extended without changing its underlying "structure".

Example of an implementation would be:

```
public class FancyRectangle : Object
{
    public string Name { get { return this.GetPropertyValueString("Name"); } set { this.AddProperty("Name", value); } }
    public string Description { get { return this.GetPropertyValueString("Description"); } set { this.AddProperty("Description", value); } }
    public float Height { get { return this.GetPropertyFloat("Height"); } set { this.AddProperty("Height", value); } }
    public float Lenght { get { return this.GetPropertyFloat("Lenght"); } set { this.AddProperty("Lenght", value); } }
}
```

Of course all these objects could perform operations such as:

```
FancyRectangle rect1 = new FancyRectangle();

rect1.AddRelationship(rect2);
rect1.ToXml();
rect2.ToJson();
```

Also

- context.Save() to persist all objects,properties, relationships into a database for example, I would also like to be able to serialize and Deserialise the whole "Data Context"
- I would like to do Context1.Compare(Context2) and operations of the such that process all Data Context objects (Objects, Properties and relationships)

I would like to implement these behaviour in the abstract classes so when Object class gets implemented (i.e FancyRectangle Class) I don't have to code any of these common behaviour and properties into it that are all inherited as I want one implementation of .ToXml(), .ToJson()

I would like this core library to be very portable and flexible to be extended easily and that wouldn't limit its implementations very much.

This Core Library would probably interact with readers and UIs and Presenters.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

I find your inheritance structure pretty difficult to understand. Maybe it makes more sense to you as you understand the motivations behind it, but object oriented patterns through inheritance usually work through classes *being* their superclasses. Are properties, relationships, contexts and objects *really* the same thing - behaviors? I'm inclined to think that they are not. However, it would really help to have more specific details about your particular case.

A good set of heuristics to keep in mind when doing object oriented design is SOLID ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)).

Your design fails the single responsibility principle and interface (abstract class) segregation principle because of your very broad inheritance structure. Your objects are responsible for serializing themselves, comparing themselves, saving themselves, and displaying themselves. That's a lot of responsibility! It would be better to other classes take care of things like display, data persistence, comparison - let the objects maintain their state and be ignorant of the other concerns of your application. That way, you can change *how* those concerns are implemented, but your objects are unaffected. This makes your application cleaner and easier to maintain.

I would propose a different approach in thinking about your structure here. You'll want to make your interfaces smaller and more focused. Even if every class in your application needs to have a dynamically generated list of `Properties` (why?), that should be a very low-level interface, perhaps `IPropertyHaving`, from which all your other interfaces inherit - but without any other functionality. By keeping your interfaces small, you don't need to worry about such a tightly-coupled design. However, I would suggest that it is unlikely for all of your application classes to need to maintain a list of their own properties. In any case:

```
//Or abstract classes, depending on which makes more sense
interface IPropertyHaving
{
    List<IProperty> Properties { get; }
    void Add(Property property);
    //etc.
}
```

Note that the Properties property is get-only, as it's unlikely that you'll want consumers of the interface to be able to replace the list of properties entirely.Your objects interface can inherit from this, but define object-specific functionality.

```
interface IObject : IPropertyHaving 
{
    string ToXml();
    string ToJson();
    //Shared object properties
}
```

These objects maintain their own data/state. They know how to serialize themselves, and they have properties, but that's all.

You'll want to have an interface or class that "ties together" your application functionality - the idea of a context is a good one.

```
interface IDataContext : IPropertyHaving //?
{
    List<IObject> Objects { get; }
    void Save(IObject entity);
    IRelationshipManager RelationshipManager { get; }
    IObjectComparer ObjectComparer { get; }
    //Collection manipulation functions, etc.
}
```

Now your data context is only responsible for maintaining your collection of IObjects and saving/retrieving/etc. This frees your objects from the responsibility of CRUD-ing themselves. By using interfaces you can switch out case-specific implementations for your application requirements. Note that your context is only directly responsible for maintaining the state of the application as a whole - it has your collection of objects, but it delegates much of the other functionality to separate interfaces, which are composed into the context.

Likewise you can define an `IObjectComparer` interface which has a single method, `Compare(IObject first, IObject second)`. Your context can then contain an IObjectComparer. This means that although your context is capable of comparing objects, you can exchange or modify *how* your objects are compared without affecting any other code.

You can also have an `IRelationshipManager` class which tracks, creates or retrieves relationships. Again, this can be tied together in your context. Your application can then maintain a single `IContext`, as well as an `IDisplayManager` or something (this will likely be part of your GUI framework - is this WPF?) that knows how to write your objects to a screen.

With more detail about your specific case, we'll be able to provide better advice.

Comment: Hi NWard, that was a very good start. Thanks very much. I've just added requirements and other details around your reply. It is important that I get this design right. I've been reading about solid but probably need more experience implementing them. I see you tend to segregate a lot your functionality with interfaces. Why would you create an interface for IObject or IDataContext? what are the benefits of it instead of using an Abstract Class for example? Thanks very much!

Comment: Typically I use abstract classes when I have method implementations or protected data fields that I want to be shared among all subclasses. In the case of your Properties it sounds like an abstract class which handles the properties and serialization methods may be the best idea. Let me re-write some of this answer in light of your recent update later today.

Comment: Thanks very much. What are your feelings towards a completely decoupled architecture?. I heard that maintenance can become very frustrating and finding problems can be a real pain. I would appreciate your input in this design. Having an abstract class "Behaviour" on my second example sounds similar to your new approach where all generic objects inherit from. Thanks very much, Looking forward to your input. –